# Can I replace Shimano 105 5500 shifters and derailers with new Sora R3000 ones?

Tags: road-bike, shimano, compatibility, groupsets

I have a 2000 Klein Quantum
(this one, 2x9 speed: https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/value-guide/product/45657/)
My shifters have been replaced once already with used 105 (also 5500), but now they have a lot of issues and I would slowly like to upgrade the whole groupset.

Can I start by switching out the shifters and derailers with new Sora R3000 parts (also 9 speed)? Or would I have issues with the brakes/crankset/etc?
This would put me back on the road while I save for the rest.
Thanks for any help, this is my first time here.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I start by switching out the shifters and derailers with new Sora R3000 parts (also 9 speed)?

All Shimano 9-speed parts use the same derailleur pull ratio (except the front derailleur pull ratio can vary between MTB / road components). Thus, you don't even need to change the derailleur, just changing the shifters is enough.

The STI levers are short-pull levers compatible with any cantilever or caliper brake. They are not compatible with V-brakes. As your old STI shifter/levers were short-pull too, no changes there.

Just be sure to select the Sora 2x9 parts instead of going for Sora 3x9 parts.

I'm not sure what issues you have but as the STI levers are expensive, please be sure to eliminate the possibility of issues coming from some other parts first. Perhaps your bike needs new inner and outer cables instead of needing new shifters?

Comment: *"All Shimano 9-speed parts use the same derailleur pull ratio"* That is only true for the 9 speeds at the rear, not those 2 speeds at the front.

Comment: Notably, there is no compatibility between Sora 3000 and Sora 3500  FD and ST in https://productinfo.shimano.com/download/?path=pdfs/archive/2017-2018_Compatibility_v030_en.pdf

Comment: juhist, thank you! My list shifter hasn't been working for years and I haven't been able to fix it. Until recently I have only used the right to shift up and down with the rear derailer, but it jamed a few days ago. I might be able to fix the right one, or adjust the derailer, but I also want to upgrade.

Comment: Vladimir F, Thank you for the clarification. I may buy the levers first and see how it goes.

Comment: @Milchman You are much higher chance of luck with the older generation shifter for the front derailleur.

Comment: @VladimirF, I don't understand what you mean. Are you saying I should try to find new 105 5500 shifters?

Comment: @Milchman I am saying that the newest Sora 3000 left shifter is NOT compatible. Nothing more, nothing less. They use the modern pull ratio that was originally introduced with the 11 speed groupsets. Sora 3500 might work.

Comment: @Milchman: Just make sure the shifters are actually broken (I once had pawl break inside a left 105 5600 shifter), not just gunked up. And as juhist already said, make sure it’s not an issue with the cables or the derailleur. STI shifters rarely break.

Comment: @Milchman what he means is that if you get the Sora shifters, you should get a new front derailleur at the same time. People give some strange answers on here.

Comment: @JoeK You are welcome to give better answers. These were just comments. I only added a quick answer with the hope the question might stop reappearing.

Comment: I ordered a Sora FD as well, unfortunately it looks like you have to break the chain to instal it, whereas the 105 had a simple screw to open the cage. Thanks for all the information.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your rear shifter by a Sora 3000 one. However, you CANNOT simply replace your front shifter with a Sora 3000 one unless you also change the front derailleur.

The front derailleur cable pull ratio has changed. You need some older type, such as Sora 3500. You can verify the compatibility on the Shimano website https://productinfo.shimano.com/download/?path=pdfs/archive/2017-2018_Compatibility_v030_en.pdf (and other older or more recent version of your liking).

Comment: He could also replace the front derailleur, it's not like they're expensive. So yes hecan; he needs shifters *and* a front derailleur

Comment: Sure, I think the point was clear.